# Javascript sort algorithm for linked sections objects array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have the following array of objects which need to be sorted in a special way:

```
var sections = [
    {begin:"test3", end:"test4"},
    {begin:"test5", end:"test2"},
    {begin:"test2", end:"test3"},
];
```

All sections are linked together via `sectionA.end == sectionB.begin` so the result of the sort operation should be:

```
var sectionsSorted = [
    {begin:"test5", end:"test2"},
    {begin:"test2", end:"test3"},
    {begin:"test3", end:"test4"}
];
```

I want to do this in the `Array.prototype.sort()` method. I realised that the beginning section could be found if the `begin` is not an `end` in any section but from there on I am lot. Has anybody an idea how to implement something like this?

I did a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fxmnxh8L/1/

Comment: What defines the starting point of the new order? The largest `begin`? Or is there only one order fullfilling the conditions, and you have to serach the correct combination? Is the data guaranteed to contain an unbroken chain of the chainable values?

Comment: The starting point is defined by `section.begin not in [all sections.end]`. Hopefully I described it properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var sections = [
    {begin:"test3", end:"test4"},
    {begin:"test5", end:"test2"},
    {begin:"test2", end:"test3"},
];

sections.sort((s1, s2) => {
  return s1.end === s2.begin ? -1 : 1;
});

console.log(sections);
```

EDIT: the above solution doesn't work (see comments to know why). Take a look at the below solution that use a recursive approach to compare two given sections:

```js
var sections = [    
    {begin: "test4", end: "test7"},
    {begin: "test5", end: "test2"},
    {begin: "test7", end: "test8"},
    {begin: "test2", end: "test3"},
    {begin: "test3", end: "test4"},
    {begin: "test8", end: "test9"}
];

var sectionsMap = sections.reduce((m, o) => {
    m[o.begin] = o;
    return m;
}, {});

function compare(a, b) {
    if (!sectionsMap[a.end]) {
        return 1;
    } else if (sectionsMap[a.end].begin === b.begin) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return compare(sectionsMap[a.end], b);
    }
}

sections.sort(compare);

console.log(sections);
```

Comment: Looks great the only thing is `test5` should be on the top. It is the first section

Comment: test5 is on the top

Comment: When I use the `Run code snippet` from Stackoverflow I get different result. I also tried it in the JSFiddle. Maybe it is not properly determining the overall beginning?

Comment: Try to change the callback return to: return s1.end === s2.begin ? -1 : s2.end === s1.begin ? 1 : 0;

Comment: you may try with more than 3 objects. thenproblem with this approach is, you have no relative order of two not connected objects. With valuse like numbers or strings, where a defined order is given, you actually don't know the order of some tokens.

Comment: btw, in edge, you get a nonexpected result.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks, I understand the problem

Comment: your edit looks good! The complexity is a little bit higher but that doesn't bother me.

Answer (score 1):

You can not sort the array with [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), because you need to have a stable sorting with defined predecessor, item and successor, which is not given, only if you view at two elements.

So you need a different approach by chaining all parts and get then the result out of the parts.

```js
var sections = [{ begin: "test3", end: "test4" }, { begin: "test5", end: "test2" }, { begin: "test2", end: "test3" }],
    nodes = Object.create(null),
    begin = Object.create(null),
    end = Object.create(null),
    result;

sections.forEach(function (o) {
    nodes[o.begin] = o;
    begin[o.begin] = { a: [o.begin, o.end] };
    end[o.end] = begin[o.begin];

    if (begin[o.end]) {
        begin[o.end].a.unshift(o.begin);
        begin[o.begin] = begin[o.end];
        delete begin[o.end];
        delete end[o.end];
    }

    if (end[o.begin]) {
        Array.prototype.splice.apply(begin[o.begin].a, [0, 1].concat(end[o.begin].a));
        end[o.begin].a = begin[o.begin].a;
        delete begin[o.begin];
        delete end[o.end];
    }
    delete end[o.begin];
});

result = Object.keys(begin).map(function (k) {
    return begin[k].a.slice(0, -1).map(function (n) {
        return nodes[n];
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: makes sense somehow. I also thought about a solution like that but thought it would be nice to have a solution without extra data structure. If I cannot find any other solution I will accept yours! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
function compare(a,b) {
 if (a.end < b.end)
    return -1;
 if (a.end > b.end)
    return 1;
      }

sections.sort(compare);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/Lu3wqt0v/1/

Comment: The problem is the sorting doesn't depend on the values of `begin` and `end` (I mean in terms of comparison. So `a.end < b.end` compares the values and not the linking. Simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lu3wqt0v/2/
I exchanged the test2 <-> test3