# Sorting Javascript array by comparing objects with different key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort bellow array:

```
var joins = [
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "country",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "state",
    "foreignColumnName": "country_id",
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "state",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "city",
    "foreignColumnName": "state_id",
    "index": 2
  },
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "city",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "address",
    "foreignColumnName": "city_id",
    "index": 3
  },
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "address",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "user",
    "foreignColumnName": "address_id",
    "index": 4
  },
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "user_status",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "user",
    "foreignColumnName": "status_id",
    "index": 5
  }
]
```

by using bellow code:

```
joins.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.foreignTableName === b.joinTableName) return 1; //b comes first
  else if (a.joinTableName === b.foreignTableName) return -1; //a comes first
  else return 0; //no change
});
```

The result is:

```
[
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "state",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "city",
    "foreignColumnName": "state_id",
    "index": 2
  },
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "country",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "state",
    "foreignColumnName": "country_id",
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "address",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "user",
    "foreignColumnName": "address_id",
    "index": 4
  },
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "city",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "address",
    "foreignColumnName": "city_id",
    "index": 3
  },
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "user_status",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "user",
    "foreignColumnName": "status_id",
    "index": 5
  }
]
```

This is not what I expected -- I expect that the elements with indexies 2 and 1 come after the element with index 3. What is wrong?

To add some more details, this is for creating a MySql query statement from an object field definition table, which defines the fields of a business object by using data from the underlayer DB of another production system. The above part is for creating the `JOIN` subclause.

P.S., Here is what I want:

```
[
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "address",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "user",
    "foreignColumnName": "address_id",
    "index": 4
  },
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "city",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "address",
    "foreignColumnName": "city_id",
    "index": 3
  },
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "state",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "city",
    "foreignColumnName": "state_id",
    "index": 2
  },
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "country",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "state",
    "foreignColumnName": "country_id",
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "user_status",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "user",
    "foreignColumnName": "status_id",
    "index": 5
  }
]
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well. it is not clear in which order you want to get `foreignTableName`.

Comment: I believe you want to return -1 in the first if, and 1 in the second.

Comment: @NinaScholz -- added. Thanks.

Comment: you can not take sort to get a connected list. in this case, you need to take another approach.

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry I did not get the idea -- it looks just logical, same as comparing on the same key-pairs.

Comment: please have a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47284396/1447675

Comment: @NinaScholz your observation is right. However, I did not understand your words "because you need to have a stable sorting with defined predecessor, item and successor, which is not given, only if you view at two elements" there. Then I tried to use bubbleSort instead of Javascript array `sort` method and got it.

Comment: @zipper, fine, if it works, then you got it.

Comment: @NinaScholz I managed to make my own, see bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't know the mechanism of `Array.prototype.sort`, I tried the same logic with bubbleSort and print the steps and found the problem.

At the initial of each loop, the bubbleSort takes a leftmost element in the unsorted array as the "bubble", and tries to swap it to one step right at a time, if the element is smaller than it's right-neighbor, then takes the right-neighbor as the bubble --thus when the bubble goes to the rightmost it contains the biggest among the un-sorted elements.

My problem is, the element in my target set is not always comparable to another, so I cannot bubble the "biggest" to the rightmost --there is no such "biggest". the elements in my target set are "partially" orderable: I can set orders among some of them, but not all.

With this in mind, I come with an idea: I should sort those orderable elements into segments/chains and then merge them. Bellow, I call it `mergeSort` (I know there is a famous merge-sort but I cannot remember its mechanism so mine can be inconsistent with the typical merge-sort).

```
function mergeSort(arr, compFn) {
  let res = [];
  while (arr.length > 0) {
    res = res.concat(makeChain(arr.splice(0, 1)[0], compFn));
  }
  return res.filter(n => n);

  function makeChain(obj, compFn) {
    let res = [obj];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (isEmpty(arr[i])) return;
      let flag = compFn(obj, arr[i]);
      if (flag < 0) {
        res = res.concat(makeChain(arr.splice(i, 1)[0], compFn));
      } else if (flag > 0) {
        res = makeChain(arr.splice(i, 1)[0], compFn).concat(res);
      }
    }
    return res;
  }

}
```

Then I can still use the same compareFunction:

```
joins = mergeSort(joins, (a, b) => {
  if (a.foreignTableName === b.joinTableName) return 1; //b comes first
  else if (a.joinTableName === b.foreignTableName) return -1; //a comes first
  else return 0; //no change
});
```

This generated the sorted array I expected.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have one approach that first assigns a `level` to every object, the level is defined by the `index` of the root ancestor of an object and the `level of deep` that the object is inside the linked list it belong to. After adding this new `lvl` property, we just can sort using this new property. I don't believe this approach will be so good on performance, but maybe could fit for your needs.

```js
var joins = [
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "country",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "state",
    "foreignColumnName": "country_id",
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "state",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "city",
    "foreignColumnName": "state_id",
    "index": 2
  },
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "city",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "address",
    "foreignColumnName": "city_id",
    "index": 3
  },
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "address",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "user",
    "foreignColumnName": "address_id",
    "index": 4
  },
  {
    "joinType": "INNER JOIN",
    "joinTableName": "user_status",
    "joinColumnName": "id",
    "foreignTableName": "user",
    "foreignColumnName": "status_id",
    "index": 5
  }
];

// Find the object with the table a foreign key is referencing.

const findParent = (fTable) => joins.find(x => x.joinTableName === fTable);

// Recursive method that assigns a level to an object based on the position
// they have on the linked list they belong to.

const getLevel = (fTable, index, lvl) =>
{
    let parent = findParent(fTable);
    return (fTable && parent) ?
           getLevel(parent.foreignTableName, parent.index, lvl + 1) :
           index + "-" + lvl;
}

// Maps the input data to adds the level property to each object.

let newInput = joins.map(obj =>
{
    obj.lvl = getLevel(obj.foreignTableName, obj.index, 0);
    return obj;
});

// Sorts the new generated data based on the level property. Since the
// lvl property is a string, we use "localeCompare()" to compare.

let sortedInput = newInput.sort((a, b) => a.lvl.localeCompare(b.lvl));

// Shows the sorted data.

console.log(sortedInput);
```